# Access model data in ClientRowTemplate (Telerik MVC Grid control)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using the Telerik MVC Grid control...

I understand you can use the `<#= SomeData #>` syntax when you wish to stamp your data as a string within the `ClientRowTemplate` but what if you want to do server-side logic on some of your data in your `ClientRowTemplate`?  How could you achieve this?

I have a bool, called `CanDelete`, in my model that I want to check and if it's `true`, show a DeleteButton.  The code I have currently looks something like this:

```
.ClientRowTemplate(grid => "<div><#= SomeField #> " + grid.DeleteButton(null, GridButtonType.Image) + "</div>")
```

This works fine if I want to show the DeleteButotn every time but I want to check another field in my model first to determine whether to show it or not.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way, but you can put conditional logic in your template.

```
.ClientRowTemplate(grid => "<# if(CanDelete) { #><div><#= SomeField #> " + grid.DeleteButton(null, GridButtonType.Image) + "</div><# } #>")
```

What you put in the conditional is limited. I have been able to do this successfully with a bool and an int comparison, but not with a string comparison.